# Cannot create property on string

Tags: javascript

I have stumbled on a weird issue when trying to recursively set properties on an empty object with the following code:

**Simplified code**

```
const birthdays = {};

// Loop -> Passing day, id and birthday
birthdays[day] = day;
birthdays[day][id] = birthday;
```

Example of day: `'01012017'`

Example of id: `1547`

Example of birthday: `{name: John}`

**Error message**

```
Cannot create property '123' on string '06012017'
```

I saw some people with Angular having this issue but their answer don't solve anything for me (as is angular specific syntax etc).

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. What is your question?

Comment: @FelixKling I was messing up the init of `birthdays[day]` with the day itself, using the `birthdays[day] = {}` fixed it for me.

Comment: There's no error in that code. It's perfectly valid Javascript. You can do this: `birthdays['01012017'] = '01012017'` and then this `birthdays['01012017'][1547] = {name: 'John'}`, and it will NOT trigger any such error.

Comment: @GetFree - that is a tricky one - but you are right because Strings allow setting (characters) by numeric index causes no error - the code is valid but you can't access that value later `birthdays['01012017'][1547] === undefined`

Comment: If the day value is a string `let sDay='01012017'; birthdays[sDay]=sDay;` then ⚡ `sDay.id='birthday'` causes the TypeError as scalar system types (String, Number, Boolean,...) in general are "frozen" (can not have any new props assigned).
`Object.isFrozen('01012017') === true`. To avoid this but keep the "string" feeling - a wrapper class could be used: `class Value{constructor(v){this.value=v;}toString(){return this.value;}}` making `birthdays[day]=new Value(day);birthdays[day][1547]={name:"John"}` is error free and `birthdays[day]` has props and `String(birthdays[day]) === '01012017'`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Empty Objects need to be individually created before their values are assigned. And use of `const` is not a good idea here, anyway, it's just my suggestion.

```js
const birthdays = {};
var day = 123;
var id = 21;
var birthday = 2016;
// Loop -> Passing day, id and birthday
birthdays[day] = {};
birthdays[day][id] = birthday;
```

Comment: It solved my issue! I was messing up the init of `birthdays[day]` with the day itself, using the `birthdays[day] = {}` totally worked

Comment: Use of const is perfectly fine and best practice here. It means that you are not going to reassign a variable. Don't be confused with immutability of value

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error message `TypeError: Cannot create property 'false' on boolean 'false'` in Node 14.3.0 (ES 2019), using the new Javascript semicolon-less syntax, with a variable declaration and assignment followed by a destructuring assignment on the next line.

The code that caused the error:

```
var a = b ()
[c, d] = e ()
```

Solved by:

```
var a = b ()
;
[c, d] = e ()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define the object:

```
let birthdays = {};
```

Then, get the attributes you want to use in that object:

```
let day = '20210203';
let id = 77;
```

Afterwards, create a pair of the two attributes (bear in mind the square brackets, that's an ES6 feature to use the variable as a key):

```
let pair = {[id]: day};
```

And, finally, form up the main object like this:

```
birthdays = {...birthdays, ...pair};
```

And voila, you've added a kvp to an empty object and you won't be getting the "Cannot create property '77' on string '20210203'" error anymore.

Comment: This is incorrect. Objects are not iterable so you can't use the spread syntax with them. This will trigger an error: `...birthdays`, as well as this `...pair`.

Comment: where exactly do you see iterations, @GetFree? try all of the lines in your browser console and you will see that there is no error thrown whatsoever.

Comment: I did try them. The 3 dots syntax `...` requires the value to its right to be iterable. That's why this `...birthdays` will throw an error.

Comment: @GetFree, the spread operator is valid on both an iterable and an object.  You can spread the contents of an array, or spread out the key-value pairs.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax