# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'value' on string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this error as soon as I input a second character:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'value' on string 'a'
```

The code so far:

```js
function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState({
    name: "",
    value: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setObject((object) => (object.value = e.target.value));
    console.log(object);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type something" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the `setState` function is not being handled properly here.

*Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does not automatically merge update objects.*

---

So we can say that the real question is:

**How to change a single property of a state object using useState hook?**

**Solution 1:** You can return a new object by spreading over previous state.

```js
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setObject((prevObject) => ({ ...prevObject, value: e.target.value }));
    console.log(object);
  };
```

<del>**Solution 2:** You can create a new state object and completely replace the old one.</del>

> In this solution, you cannot guarantee that object has been refreshed to the latest version.
> Also, even if it were, you're setting object to be the same object reference it currently holds, therefore it will not be recognised as a change and the value will not be set.

```js
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const temp = object;
    temp["value"] = e.target.value;
    setObject(temp);
    console.log(object);
  };
```

---

*See these questions:*

1. *[Updating and merging state object using React useState() hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook)*
2. *[Cannot create property on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510186/cannot-create-property-on-string)*

Comment: Actually, solution 2 simply doesn't work. In that solution, you cannot guarantee that `object` has been refreshed to the latest version. Also, even if it were, you're setting `object` to be the same object reference it currently holds, therefore it will not be recognised as a change and the value will not be set. You should never update a state object in this way. Solution 1 is the correct solution though, so just go with that.